# Cloud Functions for Firebase onWrite trigger not called when parent is deleted

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am listening to this path using Cloud Functions onWrite:

`/msgr/{a}/users/{b}`

Now assume that there are 100 children under `users`.

When I delete `/msgr/x/users/12` from the console, the onWrite trigger is run, which is as expected.

However, if I delete `/msgr/x/users` from the console, the onWrite function is not run at all. I expect that the onWrite trigger is run 100 times, as much as the number of children under `users`.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: May be related to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/-udC4weRFO0

Comment: I don't know if "Tom Larkworthy" is a Firebase staff that confirms the bug and said that the bug will be fixed on May 10th, since I can't seem to open the user profile. I hope it is so. Thanks!

Comment: Tom is indeed a Firebaser. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fellow Firebaser [Tom said on the firebase-talk mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/-udC4weRFO0):

> Thanks for reporting, I found two bugs, I hope to have them rolled out to production by May 10th.

**Update: this problem has been fixed. Leaving my original response for posterity.**

Comment: fixed... meaning an onDelete trigger will be invoked upon a parent deletion? I still get nothing invoked. I would expect to be able to choose between onDelete() and onDeleteIncludesParents(). Please advise.