# Firebase google cloud function onWrite not called upon delete?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When I create a new item my pushToLeaderBoards function gets called but not when I delete it, so when is onWrite supposed to get called?  The docs say it should get called on delete (in my android app I use targetref.setValue(null)).  How else can I fire a google cloud function upon a delete?

```
//node code
exports.pushToLeaderBoards = functions.database
    .ref('/leaderboards/userLeaderboards/{userID}/{class}/{subject}/{pushID}')
    .onWrite(event => {...
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug out when deleting groups of items. Could it be that you're hitting that? If so, the fix should be going into production on May 10. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654626/cloud-functions-for-firebase-onwrite-trigger-not-called-when-parent-is-deleted

Comment: Probably.   I found a work-around for now - before I delete the object I set one of its primitive children to null.  Then another version of my pushToLeaderBoards function (pushToLeaderBoards2)  is called which does the second deletion which I want to happen.  The goal is to delete a globalLeaderboard entry when the corresponding userLeaderboard entry is deleted.   Thanks!

Comment: I think I indeed saw that workaround mentioned somewhere, so sounds good for now. Only a few more days until the fix is out!

Comment: It seems to be fixed now.